# How to check the i-check box after the particular input element

Tags: jquery, icheck

```
<input type="hidden" name="services_hidden" id="services_hidden_1" acc_code="620040" desc="noolssl" project="2733773" cost_center_1="4564" cost_center_2="" cost_center_3="" cost_center_4="" cost_center_5="" price="1000.000000" discount="5.000000" vatcode="E4" check="po-s-7">
<div class="checkbox">
      <label>
 <input class="i-check copy_services_poid" name="copy_services[1]" type="checkbox" value="1">
      </label>
</div>
```

How to select the above checkbox.

i have used the coding as

```
alert($('input[check="po-s-7"]').attr('type')); 

 $('input[check="po-s-7"]').find('i-check').addClass('checked');
```

Comment: i want to make  the copy_services[1] to be selected

Comment: The `input` tag is a [void element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#syntax-elements), so it cannot have any child elements within it. However, jQuery's `find()` searches through the child elements of the selector. In this case, you are unable to `find('i-check')`. Consider accessing the checkbox directly?

Comment: i even used the siblings() method in jquery

Comment: Are you able to come up with a fiddle for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to `find()` the class `i-check` as the `<input>` is a void element. What you can do is to access the checkbox directly.

Also, as `checked` is an attribute (and not a class), you need to use `prop('checked', true)` instead. For example:
`$('input[name="copy_services[1]"]').prop('checked', true);`

Try taking a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uej9tmnp/).